# Browser blocking new Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

On my form I have a submit that will open a new window:

```
<form class="form" id="formTest" action="../../newWindow.cfm" method="post" target="_blank" >
```

In my button click, I reload my current page changing the url parameters and call my submit. So, I need to reload the page changing the url parameters and open a new Window:

```
    $("#formTest").submit();

var url = 'home.cfm?m=' + $("#urlParam").val();
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

My problem is that the browser is blocking the new window, but because I reload the page I can't see the option to allow the browser to open a new window. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You probably can't fix it, popup-blockers are there for a reason, to block annoying websites.

Comment: To troubleshoot, forget all that javascript and put a simple submit button in your form.  If a new window or tab opens, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: But I need to open the new window and also reload the current page.

Comment: There's a simple policy in modern browsers: a window that is not explicitly triggered by the user (e.g. click event) or traversed through hidden elements is considered as undesired pop-up. Unless the user explicitly allows the site to do this, you cannot make this work.

Comment: Okay... I would like it ask the user to allow pop-up, but it reload the current page and the browser doesn't request the user to allow pop-up

Comment: Popup notifications appear different across browsers, so it's generally difficult to inform the user about it, e.g. in Chrome it's so unobtrusive that you explicitly need to explain the user how to do it. You better think of a way to avoid the reload/open new page to begin with.